# How can I trust my doctor and what he said

Tags: cough, otolaryngology

I have been coughing for around 3 months now, with a feel of air flow on my throat. I went to my family doctor, who said it was reflux from my stomach that went out to my throat and made like red things on my throat that make me cough. I wasn't convinced so I went to another doctor who said the same and gave me Esomeparzol to reduce stomach acidity (Even I don't feel an acid taste at all), and that made me go to an Otolaryngologist who said that I have allergies in my throat due to my nose secretions and he did Nasopharyngolaryngoscopy to be sure of that.

I am not convinced. I am not seeking any medical advice here. I worry that I have a tumor in my lung that makes me cough (though no blood, or anything else other than the cough for 3 months now). I know my doctors are right. **But how do I stop being nervous?** How can I trust my doctor ?

Comment: I don't get what you want from us... Usually they know what they do and wouldn't let you with an untreated tumor. Apart from that, where did you get the idea that a tumor in your lungs will make you cough? To me it seems you just visit as many doctors as possible until someone tells you that you do have a tumor. From what I have read here, these are not classic symptoms for tumors .

Comment: Actually, it is a request for medical advice. You're asking us to either confirm or overrule two doctors who have examined you, and that makes the question off topic.

Comment: I know my doctors are right. But how do I stop being nervous. That's my question.

Comment: Edit your question to add that that is your primary question, to avoid having a cluttered question that doesn't ask what you really want to know.  Editing it will help improve the site quality.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that a tumour in your lung can make you cough (I coughed uncontrollably day and night until mine went away) but a million much milder things can do that too. If you had a cancer growing in your lungs you would have symptoms other than just coughing. Your doctors would notice.

If the "acid reflux" and the "allergies" treatments have not helped, it's good for you to continue to investigate so you can get some relief. It's not good for you to decide it's the worst possible thing, that will just upset you for no benefit. Keep communicating with your family doctor that you want to know what is causing the cough and you want to clear it up and get relief.

Sticking with one doctor and going from them to a specialist and then back again is probably the best way to build trust, compared to going to a series of different specialists who can argue with each other through you. If you think your family doctor would let you die from tumours rather than help you, you need a different family doctor. But if it's just a matter that you can't shake your fear, work with your doctor to get that settled.

Comment: +1 for the statement "Sticking with one doctor and going from them to a specialist and then back again is probably the best way to build trust."  This is one recommended management of health anxiety or "illness anxiety disorder."  Acid reflux and allergies and asthma are very  common causes of chronic cough.  Stick with a doctor and follow treatment recommendations closely.  Partner together and follow up until you either feel you understand it, it resolves, or the symptoms are adequately managed.

Comment: Cognitive Behavioral Therapy is also a treatment for health anxiety, like other types of anxiety.

Comment: Thank you all. I would like to hear more about your coughing day and night tho

Comment: the specifics of my cough are unlikely to be useful. I was sick. It made me cough. It got really bad. I had many many symptoms in addition to the cough. Then it got better. All my symptoms are gone.

Comment: I changed the family doctor and went to Gastrointestinal and stomach doctor. He said the same. I went to ear, nose and throat doctor and said the same and had allergy and the cough will take too long to go off. I went to lung doctor and said the same. I eat well. I did lots of echos and scanners to stomack and lung and throat with full blood tests and nothing was found. Just cough from allergy ? It made me really annoyed.